# React Native/Javascript - Cannot update view after async fetch function. Invalid order of execution

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, async-await

the code I have put down below will call fetch() to recieve some data and only after fetching it will display one output. But this always fails to update the view after the async call. I'm new to this react native async calls so I'd like to have some help on this. Here is the necessary parts of the code.

```
import React from 'react'
import {StyleSheet, View, ScrollView, Alert} from 'react-native';
import {Card, Button, Text} from 'react-native-elements';
import {TextField} from 'react-native-material-textfield';

class MyScreen extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
        title: 'Title'
    });

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        const {navigation} = this.props;

        this.state = {
            loaded: false
        };
    }

    async componentWillMount() {
        let responseJson = await this.fetchData().done();
        console.log(responseJson);

        console.log('componentWillMount finished');
    }

    fetchData = async () => {
        const response = await fetch('myurl/' + GLOBAL.account_data.account.emp_number, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: new Headers({
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + GLOBAL.access_token,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            })
        });

        return await response.json();
    };

    render() {
        let view;
        console.log('in render');


        if (this.state.loaded) {
            view = <Text>Vikasitha</Text>
        } else {
            view = <Text>Buddhi</Text>
        }

        return (
            view
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    card_info: {
        flex: 1,
        height: 10
    },
    card_leave: {
        flex: 2,
        height: 30
    }
});

export default MyInfoPersonalDetailsScreen;
```

The console log are printed in the following order.

```
console.log('in render')
console.log(responseJson) //prints undefined
console.log('componentWillMount finished')
```

But if the await and async functions synchronize correctly, this should be in the order,

```
console.log(responseJson)
console.log('componentWillMount finished')
console.log('in render')
```

- Is it? (this is from my understanding.)
- Correct usage of componentWillMount? (used componentWillMount because this should execute before rendering. Not like componentDidMount)

I just want to get the flow in the correct order. It is about the order of execution when constructor, componentWillMount and render is used. Don't worry about the unused variables and missing parts.

Any help appreciated!!

Comment: read some basic fetch/setState tutorial

Comment: I was trying to add that I have gone through them, using an event like a button click the behaviour can be achieved but the issue is when used with the componentWillMount the execution order is unclear.

Comment: where did you found `async componentWillMount` ??

Comment: Can't remember but there are plenty like https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/async-await-with-react-lifecycle-methods-802e7760d802. I also do not know if it is the best practice until I get this right.

Comment: IMHO it looks a bit quirky, not popular ... try version from comments with `initialize = async ()` - this is more standard way... but i wouldn't use `await asyncSetState` - it does nothing - setState is already async, netActivity can be set w/o waiting, too (data fetched/decoded). just: `const {ip} = await res.json()
 setState({ipAddress: ip})
 StatusBar.setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible(false)`

Comment: Didn't get it. How does it help to get the execution order right? I'm already awaiting for the response.json()

Comment: don't return it, setState

Comment: learn standart `fetch() / .then / setState` flow

Comment: I have figured it out. I have been treating this react state in an angular way. It appears that the render function excutes again after every this.setState call. calling this.state.variable_name doesn't work like that. Thanks xadm.

Comment: tutorials are for this knowledge ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
  componentDidMount() {
    // just call async function in didMount
      this.fetchData();
    }

    fetchData = async () => {
        const response = await fetch('myurl/' + GLOBAL.account_data.account.emp_number, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: new Headers({
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + GLOBAL.access_token,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            })
        });

        let result =  await response.json();
        console.log(result);
        console.log(responseJson);
        console.log('componentWillMount finished');
        // update your state here
         this.setState({result});
    };
```